# unable to parse an index in pandas by date

Tags: python, pandas

I've read through several SO posts and been unable to resolve this issue I have a dataframe that spans several weeks

```
2018-10-25 16:00:03.003 tag1   6
2018-10-25 16:00:03.003 tag2   10
2018-10-25 16:00:03.003 tag3   11
2018-10-25 16:00:03.003 tag4   12
2018-10-25 16:00:03.003 tag5   9
....
```

That was created with

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f,names=['time','tag','value'],index_col=0,parse_dates=True) for f in glob.glob(path)],
                   sort=False)
```

When I try to return only a single day by index with `df.loc['2018-10-25']` it returns `KeyError: u'the label` ['2018-10-25'] is not in the [index]

How do I extract by a day with this method 
The output of `df.index()` `is TypeError: Index is not callable ?`

At @ALollz suggestion by removing parsedates and doing:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'],errors='coerce')
df.set_index('time',inplace=True)
```

which returns `KeyError: time`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Can you show the output of `df.index`

Comment: @ALollz it looks like my index is not being properly defined?

Comment: `index` is an attribute of a dataframe, but not a method, which is why it's not callable. Remove the parentheses..

Comment: Yes, you have an `Index` not a `DatetimeIndex`. The issue is that `parse_dates` will 'try' to parse the dates, but if it can't then it just keeps them as strings (and doesn't warn you about this...) Likely you have one bad date, so nothing is being converted. Instead, you should read it in as a normal column and convert with `pd.to_datetime()` with `errors='coerce`, then set the index.

Comment: @ALollz that got me going in the correct direction transfer that to an answer and I will mark it.

Comment: @risail You seem to have two `]]` in your `pd.to_datetime` function in your edit. Maybe comment out/delete the `set_index` line until you have the line before it working and are sure that it is adding a `time` column to your DataFrame.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is your separator.  Your file is space-separated, but CSV defaults to comma (head-slap).  As a result, your input parsing -- finding no commas -- retains the entire line as the input value for a single column.  df.index shows this clearly:

```
Index(['2018-10-25 16:00:03.003 tag1   6', 
       '2018-10-25 16:00:03.003 tag2   10',
       '2018-10-25 16:00:03.003 tag3   11',
       '2018-10-25 16:00:03.003 tag4   12',
       '2018-10-25 16:00:03.003 tag5   9'],
      dtype='object', name='time')
```

As a result, the input doesn't parse as a date, and is not searchable with the date facilities in Pandas.

Either insert commas into your data set, as your current parsing expects, or specify white space as the file separator.  This results in an index

```
DatetimeIndex(['2018-10-25 16:00:03.003000', '2018-10-25 16:00:03.003000',
               '2018-10-25 16:00:03.003000', '2018-10-25 16:00:03.003000',
               '2018-10-25 16:00:03.003000'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='time', freq=None)
```

... and your date-search command returns nicely:

```
                           tag  value
time                                 
2018-10-25 16:00:03.003   tag1      6
2018-10-25 16:00:03.003   tag2     10
2018-10-25 16:00:03.003   tag3     11
2018-10-25 16:00:03.003   tag4     12
2018-10-25 16:00:03.003   tag5      9
```

Comment: Hmmm ... two downvotes ... can someone point out where I went wrong with this?  It appears that I need to learn more about Pandas dates, and maybe delete this answer?  I don't want to leave garbage lying around ... but I *did* fix the problem in my sandbox, so I'm curious what I missed.

Comment: How do you know that the file is space-delimited? Was it in the question before the question was edited? I did not downvote by the way

Comment: Presentation of the data is in file form rather than a data frame display.  I took that as the data file.